# Hypernym for "company", "band" and "organization"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

I'm making a website and I'd need a hypernym to refer to company/band(/artist)/organization, so I wouldn't have to use all the words every time.

What would be a common one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a good word in your question. [*Organization*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&q=define+organisation&oq=define+organisation&gs_l=serp.3..0l10.96570.98811.0.99134.12.6.0.6.6.0.107.489.2j3.5.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..1.11.551.hp0ymQztyZU) can be used to cover all of them.

You could also expand upon the word *organization* the first time that you use it and then just use the single word in the rest of the site.